# How do I move the data in one indexed range to another in Pandas?

Tags: pandas

I would like to move all entries from column `N1` to `M1`, row `A1` to `B1`, to column `N2` to `M2`, row `A2` to `B2`. In other words, the Pandas equivalent of copying and pasting a highlighted region of cells to a different one.

For example, in this case, move `row 0, col B:C` to `row 3, col A:B`:

```
    A      B      C
0  apple  pear   banana
1
2
3
```

to

```
    A     B       C
0  apple
1
2       
3 pear  banana
```

How could I do this?

Comment: I'm not 100% on the logic - why are you moving from index 0 to index 3?

Comment: It's a trivial example which was meant as an easy way to explain the real situation. The real situation is that there is a square region of data and I just want to move it somewhere else. The real reason is because the Excel spreadsheet repeats its columns: Name Gender Address Name Gender Address. I just want to move the second repeat to the bottom of the first, and only have one set of columns: Name Gender Address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reassign the values using `.iloc()`:

```
df.iloc[3,1:3]=df.iloc[0,1:3]
df.iloc[0,1:3]=None
```

[df.iloc() Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)

**Update:**

---

Appending :

```
df.append(df.iloc[0,0:3])
```

[df.append() Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)

Comment: Thanks very much. What if the data is being added at the bottom of the currently existing data, so pandas thinks it's out of range? I mean if the dataframe has 10 rows, and you want to add 5 rows of new data starting after the 10th row, at row index 11?

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working as expected. It's like "iloc" is holding onto to the original column and row indices of the .iloc selection. Is there some way I can strip the .iloc selection of its row and column index so pandas doesn't think it should be in its original column location? I can post again in a second to explain better.

Comment: I did df = df.append(df.iloc[:, 4:8]) on a dataframe with 92 rows. It returns: [185 rows x 8 columns]. But the printout doesn't go from 1 to 185. It still goes from 1 to 92. If I check a row with df.iloc[180], it returns "Name: 88", like it's still named "88". And the data I took from columns 4:8 is still in columns 4:8. It changed rows, but not columns.

Comment: The key was to use "ignore_index = True"